# Mapstruct - Send nested entity having (one-to-many relation) in the response

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, dto, mapstruct

I have 2 entities **CallRecords** and **CallRecordOperators** with one-to-many relation as given below

```
 public class CallRecords {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default ''")
    private String callerNumber = "";

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="callrecord")
    private List<CallRecordOperators> callRecordOperators = new ArrayList<CallRecordOperators>();


   //getter setters
}

public class CallRecordOperators {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "callRecordId")
    private CallRecords callrecord;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "operatorId")
    private Operator operator;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:yy")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date startTime = new Date();

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(100) default ''")
    private String dialStatus;

   //getter setter
}
```

So if the user ask for all "CallRecords" data I also have to give "CallRecordOperators" as they are related.

Current code for Mapper and DTOs

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface CallRecordsMapper {

    CallRecordsMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CallRecordsMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source="callRecordOperators",target = "operators")
    CallRecordsDto callRecordsToCallRecordsDto(CallRecords callRecords);

    public abstract CallRecordOperatorsDto toTarget(CallRecordOperators source);

    List<CallRecordsDto> callRecordsToCallRecordsDtos(List<CallRecords> callRecords);

}

public class CallRecordsDto {

    private String callerNumber;

    private List<CallRecordOperatorsDto> operators;

    //getter setters
}

public class CallRecordOperatorsDto {

    private String callRecordsId;

    private String operatorId;
    private String operatorName;

    private String currentTime;

   // getter setter

}
```

But for above code I am getting

```
{
    "callerNumber": "9898989898",
    "operators": [{
        "callRecordsId": null,
        "operatorId": null,
        "operatorName": null,
        "currentTime": null
    }, {
        "callRecordsId": null,
        "operatorId": null,
        "operatorName": null,
        "currentTime": null
    }]
}
```

the values of operator array are null. what could be he issue?

Comment: Can you share the definitions of your target types (DTOs) as well? IIUC, you want to map the properties of one of the entries in `A#bs` to a property in the DTO for `A`. Which `B` would that be? Your best approach probably is to use an expression to select the right value: `@Mapping(target="property1", expression="java(bs.get(0).property1)")`.

Comment: @Gunnar updated the question with my actual entity. I want the list of second entity in my first entity as shown above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems your are lacking the mappings from `CallRecordOperators` to `CallRecordOperatorsDto`:

```
@Mapper
public interface CallRecordsMapper {

    CallRecordsMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CallRecordsMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source="callRecordOperators",target = "operators")
    CallRecordsDto callRecordsToCallRecordsDto(CallRecords callRecords);

    @Mapping(target = "callRecordsId", source = "callrecord.id")
    @Mapping(target = "operatorId", source = "operator.id")
    @Mapping(target = "operatorName", source = "operator.name")
    @Mapping(target = "currentTime", source = "startTime")
    CallRecordOperatorsDto callRecordOperatorsToDto(CallRecordOperators source);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a Hibernate query of `A` elements, you can fetch the related `B` elements of the `bs` collection using different strategies. Some of them are:

1. If you use HQL to construct your queries, you can do a `JOIN FETCH` or `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to populate the `bs` collection:

   ```
   String hql = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM " + A.class.getName() 
       + " a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs WHERE ...";
   ```

   This query will load all data using a single SQL query.
2. Use eager fetching of the `bs` collection, changing the `@OneToMany` annotation:

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<B> bs;
   ```

   In this case, when you run a query of `A` elements, a SQL query will be launched to retrieve the `A` data, and for each `A` object in the result, a SQL query will be executed to load the corresponding `bs` collection.
3. If you use `Criteria` to build the query, you can change the fetch mode of the `bs` collection in a way similar to the HQL `JOIN FETCH`:

   ```
   Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class);
   c.setFetchMode("bs", FetchMode.JOIN);
   c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

How about switching to a slightly different approach that also performs better? By using [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) you can define your mapping directly on the DTO classes and apply that onto a query builder to generate efficient queries that perfectly fit your DTO structure.

```
@EntityView(CallRecords.class)
public interface CallRecordsDto {
    // The id of the CallRecords entity
    @JsonIgnore
    @IdMapping("id") String getId();

    String getCallerNumber();

    @Mapping("callRecordOperators")
    List<CallRecordOperatorsDto> getOperators();
}

@EntityView(CallRecordOperators.class)
public interface CallRecordOperatorsDto {

    // The id of the CallRecordOperators entity
    @JsonIgnore
    @IdMapping("id") Long getId();

    @Mapping("callrecord.id")
    String getCallRecordId();

    @Mapping("operator.id")
    String getOperatorId();

    @Mapping("operator.name")
    String getOperatorName();

    @Mapping("startTime")
    String getCurrentTime();

    // Whatever properties you want
}
```

See how you can map the entity attributes right in your DTOs? And here comes the code for querying

```
EntityManager entityManager = // jpa entity manager
CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf = // query builder factory from Blaze-Persistence
EntityViewManager evm = // manager that can apply entity views to query builders

CriteriaBuilder<User> builder = cbf.create(entityManager, CallRecords.class)
    .where("callerNumber").eq("123456789");
List<CallRecordsDto> result = evm.applySetting(
    builder, 
    EntityViewSetting.create(CallRecordsDto.class)
).getResultList();
```

Note that this will roughly generate the following optimized query

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.callerNumber, 
    o.callrecord.id, 
    o.id,
    o.startTime,
    op.id,
    op.name
FROM CallRecords c
LEFT JOIN c.callRecordOperators o
LEFT JOIN o.operator op
WHERE c.callerNumber = :param_1
```